# How do I get the Setup Wizard to stop downloading .net 4 Client Profile?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, setup-project

I have a web application which is entirely .net 3.5. I have created a Setup project using the wizard making sure that I selected 3.5 from the targeted famework.

When I have built the setup.exe and the Windows Installer Package and I have tried to install it on a test machine it prompts straight away to download and install the .net framework 4 client profile first.

The end-user doesn't want to upgrade their servers at this time to the latest version of .net.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Double click the .msi file, seems to be installing properly. I would also like to know how to avoid this.